# Issue with child width larger than parent width

Tags: html, css

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b83cgo1t/embedded/result/)

I'm having a hard time replicating a cool [hover effect](http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/) i found on codrops. I'm using the exact same html code she is using but there is something wrong with the `<a href>` elements being larger than its parent.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    <div class="grid">
<figure class="effect-romeo">
                    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/1.jpg" alt="img05"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Wild <span>Romeo</span></h2>
                        <p>Romeo never knows what he wants. He seemed to be very cross about something.</p>
                        <a href="#">View more</a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure><figure class="effect-romeo">
                    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/1.jpg" alt="img05"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Wild <span>Romeo</span></h2>
                        <p>Romeo never knows what he wants. He seemed to be very cross about something.</p>
                        <a href="#">View more</a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure><figure class="effect-romeo">
                    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/1.jpg" alt="img05"/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Wild <span>Romeo</span></h2>
                        <p>Romeo never knows what he wants. He seemed to be very cross about something.</p>
                        <a href="#">View more</a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Copy & paste your code in your post. So it's easy rather than having to view several urls...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is because of the class `.grid figure figcaption` `padding:2em`. Remove that and check the output!! Update your css like the below and check!!

***The CSS:***

```
.grid figure figcaption{
   //padding:2em;
}
```